# Styles don't apply using react-css-modules

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, react-css-modules

Everything seems fine, there are no errors, but elements on the page are still not styled.

*webpack.config.js*

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]')
},


plugins: [
  new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css', {
    allChunks: true
  }),
],
```

*Layout.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import InteractiveMap from './InteractiveMap';
import Header from './header';
import Navigation from './navigation';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './Layout.css';

class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.mapContainer}>
         <InteractiveMap /> 
       </div>
       <div>
         <Header className={styles.header}>
            <Navigation menuItems={menuItems}/>
         </Header>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CSSModules(Layout, styles);
```

*Layout.css*

```
//testing

.mapContainer: {
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
    color: yellow;
}

.header {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

*compiled app.css*

```
.Layout__mapContainer___3yH5h: {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  color: yellow;
}

.Layout__header___2kJ4F {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

As you can see on the picture, classes are generated, applied to elements, but on the page nothing is showing. 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJkKC.png)

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In react-css-modules you use [styleName](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#extending-component-styles) instead of className:

```
<div styleName="container">
```

This should work:

```
class Layout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div styleName="mapContainer">
         <InteractiveMap /> 
       </div>
       <div>
         <Header styleName="header">
            <Navigation menuItems={menuItems}/>
         </Header>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried it already, but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(styles)`?

Comment: I get an object: `Object {mapContainer: Layout__mapContainer___3yH5h", header: "Layout__header___2kJ4F"}`

Comment: Can you add the "compiled" css file to the question?

Comment: And does it work without the extractTextPlugin? If it does work without the plugin, it means that you haven't included a reference to `app.css` in your html file.

Comment: Added the compiled css file. Here's reference in my html: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">`. Also it's not working without the extractTextPlugin and in console it shows error: `GET http://localhost:8080/app.css`. Could the problem be the wrong path to css file? I tried changing it different ways, but can't figure it out.

Comment: If the path is wrong you should see an error in the console. On a hunch - remove the `allChunks` property from the extractTextPlugin decleration.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue.. 
my problem was that I did not include the generated css stylesheet in my .html file.

Without the stylesheet

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "hero"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

With the stylesheet (fix)

```
<html>
<head>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='app.css'>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "hero"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need added prefix "module", example:

```
import styles from './Layout.module.css';
```